# The sims 3 Plumbots

Tags: pc, the-sims-3

I installed an expansion pack onto The sims 3 called "Into the future" which allows me to build robots(plumbots). They have mastered their musical skill but seem unable to form a band.  How can i form a band with plumbots so plumbots and sims can be in the same band?

Comment: I believe you have to install a Sentience trait chip or a Musical Machine trait chip into the Plumbot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a Sentience Trait Chip into the robot.

Comment: And you don't have to put a capital letter in every word.

Comment: Sorry my Ipad does that automatically